# Dialog всплывающий снизу

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать в своем приложении такое же всплывающее снизу окошку. Я так понимаю это DialogFragment но может со стилем каким то или библиотека какая. В общем, объясните что это.

[image: Dialog Windod]

Comment: Это BottomSheet из последних библиотек поддержки

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли.

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему в вашем вопросе, отметьте его верным (серая галочка слева от ответа). Таким образом здесь говорят - "Спасибо. Очень помогли". Комментарии используются не для выражения благодарности, а для уточнений вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используй [`BottomSheets`](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-persistent-bottom-sheets), он создан специально под твою задачу .

Туда можно любое `View` засунуть.
[Хорошая статья с примером](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, [этот ресурс](http://www.materialdoc.com/) гораздо лучше годится для ссылок на примеры использования различных виджетов, связанных с концепцией  *Material Design*.

Comment: @pavlofff да, ресурс действительно хороший